# Heroku error al subir bot telegram .py

Tags: heroku, telegram, telegram-bot

Hace unos días hice un Bot para telegram y lo estoy queriendo subir a heroku pero me esta tirando el siguiente error. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Modifique el archivo procfile pero no funciono, tengo todo configurado y al querer cambiar el dynos en heroku por el que cree en el procfile no me aparece. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Busque soluciones sobre el error R10 (Boot timeout) y mencionaba que modificando el procfile se solucionaria el problema, cosa que no puedo arreglar.

```
PORT = int(os.environ.get("PORT","8443"))
        HEROKU_APP_NAME = os.environ.get("HEROKU_APP_NAME")
        updater.start_webhook(listen='0.0.0.0', port=8443, url_path='TOKEN',)
        updater.bot.set_webhook(f"https://{HEROKU_APP_NAME}.herokuapp./{TOKEN}")
```

Comment: que puerto estás usando ? Si puedes agregar la parte donde lo asignas seria de ayuda

Comment: Estoy usando el puerto 8443

Comment: Le puse ese puerto debido a que en la web de la api de telgegram bot: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#fo recomiendan ese o 443, 80, 88

Comment: puedes poner ese mismo codigo como texto en vez de en imagen? para que sea mas facil publicar la respuesta

Comment: Listo ya lo modifique, gracias por el aviso!

Comment: Genial! me funciono, ya esta subido, ahora solo falta ver por que no me responde, pero mil gracias! Ya esta en heroku

Comment: Me alegra que esté funcionando, si es posible marca la respuesta como correcta para que aparezca el hilo como resuelto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku se encarga de asignar los puertos de manera dinámica y lo agrega al env.

Tu codigo esta practicamente bien, menos que terminas de asignar el puerto de manera manual en vez de dejarle a heroku asignarlo.

```
PORT = int(os.environ.get("PORT",8443))
HEROKU_APP_NAME = os.environ.get("HEROKU_APP_NAME")
updater.start_webhook(listen='0.0.0.0', port=PORT, url_path='TOKEN')
updater.bot.set_webhook(f"https://{HEROKU_APP_NAME}.herokuapp./{TOKEN}")
```